# What is my Zodiac sign?

Tags: torah-study, calendar, mysticism-kabbalah, astrology

I was born on the 25 of Tishrei 1981  at approx. 5:30 PM. According to most secular astrologers I am considered to be a Libra/Scorpio cusp sun sign (Oct. 19-25). Tishrei is considered the month of Libra according to Torah. Am I considered a Libra or a Scorpio? I seem to have some qualities of Libra and Scorpio both. How does Torah calculate astrological signs aside from months of the year? How do the calculations of Sign compare to those of secular astrology? Does the relationship between the moon and sun determine a change in my sign from year to year?

Comment: We don't really care that much about astrology as it relates to individual Jews. How you live your life is vastly more important.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_views_on_astrology

Comment: @N.T. I think Rabbah and Rabbi Akiva might have cared a little...

Comment: @Harel13 I didn't say it doesn't matter at all; just it isn't really practical to dwell on it. Your nature is what it is, and you make the best of it.

Comment: @N.T. actually, you said "we don't really care that much". You are a person who seems to me to usually stick to classic sources. These same sources speak a good deal about astrology. Perhaps you yourself have chosen to stick with "אין מזל לישראל", but certainly not everyone did. One last point: The sugiya where Rabba explains what sign he was born under and what that says about him includes explanations about the characteristics of people born under different signs. Hence, knowing what your sign is may help one understand themselves better.

Comment: Yes, your nature is what it is, but you need to understand what your nature is in the first place to know how to properly live your life (for example, be careful when drinking so as to not stab people to death). I myself, like you, am not particularly interested in astrology, but I don't see how one can simply write it off so easily. In fact, Ramchal dedicated a part of Derech Hashem to explain what the stars can teach us about how the world works.

Comment: @Harel13 I was careful not to say it was useless. I meant we're not so into it as a practical, individual matter. For example, do you know anyone who asks what someone's sign is regarding shidduchim?

Answer (score 2):

“Of the signs in heaven you shall have no fear.” (Jeremiah 10:2)

But this is what the [Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.156a) says about your birth: (Friday 6th hour is Jupiter)

> One who was born on the sixth day of the week will be a seeker. Rav Naḥman bar Yitzḥak said that this means that he will be one who seeks out mitzvot, as most of the activity on Friday involves preparation for Shabbat.
>
> One who was born under the influence of Jupiter [tzedek] will be a just person [tzadkan]. Rav Naḥman bar Yitzḥak said: And just in this context means just in the performance of mitzvot.

Beware: Its one of the [commandments](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/940309/jewish/Negative-Commandment-32.htm) of Torah not to follow or even consider astrology. Also quoted in [halachic text](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.179.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.11.16&lang2=en.). (See Rambam halacha 8 and 9 as well).

See this letter from the Lubavitcher Rebbe on [Astrology and Horoscope in Jewish Life](https://crownheights.info/letter-and-spirit/604201/weekly-letter-astrology-and-horoscope-in-jewish-life/) for a beautiful explanation why even taking any interest is an issue.

Also see Rambam's Epistle to Yemen, Chapter 3, and his Commentary on the Mishnah, Avodah Zarah 4:7.